# Error in Date parsing : CSV to DB using python

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I am trying to extract date from a CSV file using python and upload it into a database.
In CSV, the date format is dd/mm/YYYY HH:MM  like 21/04/14 17:24,7/4/2014 17:12.
Before trying to insert the date into the DB(Sql server),I am printing it on python console.
But the following format is creating an error[date between 0-9/month between 0-9/year],for instance 7/4/2014 17:12,04/02/2014 are creating the following error

```
ValueError: time data '7/4/2014 17:12' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'
```

My code is like this

```
formatter_string = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"
                for row in reader:
                        datetime_object = datetime.strptime(row[9], formatter_string)
                        row[9] = str(datetime_object.date())
                        print "insert into "+UploadTable+" values ("+nullcheckstr(row[9])+")"
```

Additional Info:`nullcheckstr()` ensures the date is not null and `row[9]` is date column in CSV

Comment: `%Y` not `%y`; it should be capital y for 4 digit year

Comment: Tried that as well.! didn't work.

Comment: and what was the error?

Comment: If you just want the date part, just split the string. `'7/4/2014 17:12'.split()[0]`.

Comment: http://codepad.org/eoucdexH

Answer (score 0):

Thanks behzad.nouri,There was an issue with the CSV file.some dates are in dd/mm/YYYY format some are in dd/mm/YY format.I've corrected them and uploaded the file into the DB.